# Add a derived attribute to existing table in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, calculated-columns

Is there any way to add a derived date/time column (to an existing table) to hold calculated running time from a race.

The values are in hours, round to 2 decimals. There are 2 columns for start time and end time in the table. Below is the last I've tried got a missing expression error.

```
ALTER TABLE race
ADD race_time AS (SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF (endtime, starttime),2)FROM race);
```

Comment: There is no `datediff()` in Oracle

Answer (score 2):

There is no `datediff()` function in Oracle and you also don't need a `SELECT` statement to create a computed column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE race
  ADD race_time AS (endtime - starttime);
```

If `endtime` and `starttime` are defined as `timestamp` the `race_time` column will be of the type `interval`.

If those two columns are `date` columns, the result will be a number representing the number of days between the two days

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used this functionality but I think it would look more like:

```
ALTER TABLE race
ADD race_time AS (ROUND(DATEDIFF (endtime, starttime),2))
```

Note that I'm not aware of a DATEDIFF function in Oracle - if you haven't written this yourself and are looking to get the number of hours between two dates it would be more like:

```
ALTER TABLE race
ADD race_time AS (ROUND((endtime - starttime)*24.0,2))
```

If your columns are timestamps, it would probably be easier to convert them to dates when doing the math

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ac1f46f8d7296754d14a3de6191dbe8

Comment: To nominate an answer as the one that best fit your needs, click the grey ✔️ mark to turn it green. If an answer is useful click the . Many answers can be marked as useful, though only one can be accepted as a best fit. While you're a new user, up votes on useful answers may not show but will be recorded and applied later when your own rep is higher

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion in a query to get the race_time prior but now I need to have this column in the table to calculate automatically without hardcoding.

Comment: That's what I gave you? Look: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3410b18c9d72931e8e179eee829ba49e - I don't insert 30 into the race time column, it works it out when I insert two dates 1.25 days apart

Comment: I got it working by moving the brackets but still need to limit the decimals. Adding a ,2 after 24 doesn't work. <ALTER TABLE race
ADD (race_time AS ((endtime - starttime)*24));>

Comment: Thanks Caius for pointing me in the right direction.  The following will limit the decimal as follows: <ALTER TABLE entry
ADD (elapsed_time number(5,2) AS ((entryfinishtime - entrystarttime)*24*60));>